# Android in-app billing динамический список товаров

Tags: in-app-purchases, android, google-play

Есть ли возможность использовать динамический список товаров? То есть загружать список с сервера, а не вбивать каждый товар в консоли разработчика?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел однозначный ответ - [НЕТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739704/android-in-app-billing-dynamic-product-list).
Но и альтернативу тоже придумал. Буду покупать какие ни будь "кредиты" в Гугл плей, и использовать их на оплату предметов, список и цена которых будет доставаться с сервера...